# Issue with google OAuth2 server to server authentication

Tags: ruby, google-admin-sdk, google-oauth

I try to get information about all my clients from Google API Admin SDK who don't turn on 2-step verification and I have a problem with authentication throw Google OAuth2 in my ruby script. Server on what I run script hasn't GUI, so it couldn't run web browser. My script:

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'
require 'google/api_client/auth/storage'
require 'google/api_client/auth/storages/file_store'
require 'fileutils'
require 'date'
require 'googleauth'
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE


APPLICATION_NAME = '2stepauthcheck'
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'use_my_own_email_from_dev_console@developer.gserviceaccount.com' # looks like 12345@developer.gserviceaccount.com
PATH_TO_KEY_FILE              = './2stepauthcheckp12.p12' # the path to the downloaded .p12 key file

date3 = (Date.today - 3)

client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => APPLICATION_NAME)
  client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :audience             => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :scope                => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly',
    :issuer               => SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    :signing_key          => Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(PATH_TO_KEY_FILE, 'notasecret')
).tap { |auth| auth.fetch_access_token! }

reports_api = client.discovered_api('admin', 'reports_v1')

def email_send(email)
  puts "Sending email"
  realname = email.sub(/@.*?$/, '').to_s.gsub(/(\S+)\.(\S+)/){ $1.to_s.capitalize + " " + $2.to_s.capitalize } #remove @domante from email address & create user name for email with capitalize letter with space
  #sent emails
  Mail.defaults {
    delivery_method  :smtp, :address    => "smtp.gmail.com",
                     :port       => 587,
                     :user_name  => 'admin@company.com',
                     :password   => '123password',
                     :enable_ssl => true

  }
  mail = Mail.new {
    to      "#{email}"
    from    'admin@company.com'
    subject '2 factor auth notification'
    text_part {
      body "Hi, #{realname} Turn on 2 factor authentication pls.\n"
    }
  }
  mail.deliver
  puts "Email sent"
end

# Put emails without 2 auth to array send_list.
results = client.execute!(
  :api_method => reports_api.user_usage_report.get,
  :parameters => { :userKey => 'all',
                   :date => date3.to_s,
                   :filds => 'parameters, entity',
                   :parameters => 'accounts:is_2sv_enrolled'})

black_list = [ "123@company.com"]

send_list = []

results.data.usageReports.each do |user|
  user.parameters.each do  |parameter|
    unless parameter['boolValue']
      send_list << user.entity.user_email
    end
  end
end

send_list.each do |email|
  if black_list.include?(email)
    next
  end
  puts email
#  email_send(email)
end
```

and I have such output:

```
/Users/val/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/val/Documents/projects/2authcheck2.rb
/Users/val/Documents/projects/2authcheck2.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
/Users/val/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126: warning: previous definition of VERIFY_PEER was here
/Users/val/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client.rb:662:in `block (2 levels) in execute!': Caller does not have access to the customers reporting data. (Google::APIClient::ClientError)
  from /Users/val/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable/retry.rb:27:in `perform'
  from /Users/val/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable.rb:15:in `retriable'
  from /Users/val/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client.rb:645:in `block in execute!'
  from /Users/val/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable/retry.rb:27:in `perform'
  from /Users/val/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable.rb:15:in `retriable'
  from /Users/val/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/google-api-client-0.8.6/lib/google/api_client.rb:636:in `execute!'
  from /Users/val/Documents/projects/devops-utils/it/2authcheck2.rb:92:in `<top (required)>'
  from -e:1:in `load'
  from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In https://console.developers.google.com Admin SDK enabled & project 2stepauthcheck has service accounts ( in admin console Authorized API clients associate with this API scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly )

So my question why it can't access to customers reporting data?

Comment: I don't see where you are setting the account you want to impersonate. In this case you have to impersonate the admin of the domain so you can call the Admin SDK on admin's behalf. check this documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/auth/service-accounts#authorizingrequests

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I read this manual and used it for writing this script. Can you say what exactly I missed in my script or settings up? Because according to this instruction I do all right.

Comment: When authenticating you have to provide the email of the user you want to impersonate. in the documentation is described as "auth_client.sub = 'user@example.org'"

Comment: thx a lot. it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to advice Gerardo I made several changes. Here is a fully working script:

```
#this script connect to admin reports and send email with notification that two-factor authentication should be on; script use oauth 2.0 for server to server applications
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'
require 'google/api_client/auth/storage'
require 'google/api_client/auth/storages/file_store'
require 'fileutils'
require 'date'
require 'googleauth'
require 'mail'
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

# variables
date3 = (Date.today - 3)
APPLICATION_NAME = 'app_name' # name of the project in developers console https://console.developers.google.com/project
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS = '123@developer.gserviceaccount.com' # email address from developers console -> apis&auth -> credential -> sservice accounts; should looks like 12345@developer.gserviceaccount.com
PATH_TO_KEY_FILE              = './key.p12' # the path to the downloaded .p12 key file
CLIENT_ID = 'clientID.apps.googleusercontent.com' # from developers console
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.usage.readonly' # from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
EMAIL = 'email@company.com' # email under which credential was created
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12('key.p12', 'notasecret') # make a key from .p12

# balack list emails arrays
black_list = [ "blacklist1@company.com", "blacklist2@company.com"]
send_list = [] # empty array for emails from api call results


# get the environment configured authorization
client = Google::APIClient.new({
                                   application_name: APPLICATION_NAME
                               })
# make authorization
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :scope => SCOPE,
    :issuer => SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    :sub => EMAIL,
    :signing_key => key)
client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

# api discovery
reports_api = client.discovered_api('admin', 'reports_v1')

# send emails method
def email_send(email)
  puts "Sending email"
  realname = email.sub(/@.*?$/, '').to_s.gsub(/(\S+)\.(\S+)/){ $1.to_s.capitalize + " " + $2.to_s.capitalize } #remove @domante from email address & create user name for email with capitalize letter with space
  #sent emails
  Mail.defaults {
    delivery_method  :smtp, :address    => "smtp.gmail.com",
                     :port       => 587,
                     :user_name  => 'email@company.com',
                     :password   => 'pass',
                     :enable_ssl => true

  }
  mail = Mail.new {
    to      "#{email}"
    from    'email@company.com'
    subject '2 factor auth notification'
    text_part {
      body "Dear #{realname},\n
it looks as if you have not turned on the two-factor authentication.
Please see  the link to activation: https://accounts.google.com/SmsAuthConfig.\n"
    }
  }
  mail.deliver
  puts "Email sent"
end

# make call to api
results = client.execute!(
  :api_method => reports_api.user_usage_report.get,
  :parameters => { :userKey => 'all',
                   :date => date3.to_s,
                   :filds => 'parameters, entity',
                   :parameters => 'accounts:is_2sv_enrolled'})

# put emails without 2 auth to array send_list.
results.data.usageReports.each do |user|
  user.parameters.each do  |parameter|
    unless parameter['boolValue']
      send_list << user.entity.user_email
    end
  end
end

# send notification to emails exclud emails from blacklist
send_list.each do |email|
  if black_list.include?(email)
    next
  end
  puts email
  email_send(email)
end
```